# Function to convert seconds to time

Tags: php

I have this function that includes an array of tokens for time:

```
function TimeAgo($time, $ret = '') {
        $time = time() - strtotime($time); // to get the time since that moment
        $tokens = array (
        'year' => 31536000,
        'month' => 2592000,
        'week' => 604800,
        'day' => 86400,
        'hour' => 3600,
        'minute' => 60,
        'second' => 1
        );
}
```

I am going to check if `$ret` equals one of the names in the array (year, month etc.) and if it does, I want to convert `$time` to the selected

How can I convert `$time` to one of the tokens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
return (isset($tokens[$ret])) ? $time/$tokens[$ret] : $time;
```

Comment: Ah... Wow. That's nice. I would make it `!empty()` because it is being set as default variable.

Comment: if $ret = ''; then $tokens[''] needs to be checked isset or not

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I guess it is better you use `array_key_exists`.